# Custom scoped increment SQL column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `users` table and `posts` table. A user has many posts.

`CREATE TABLE users (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(10));`

`CREATE TABLE posts (id INT, user_id INT, text TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id, user_id));`

My question is, **How do I create an automatically increment mechanism to increment the `id` of a user's post but scoped to the user (the `user_id`) only.**

For example,

user `1` has 2 posts, the first post has id `1`, the second post has id `2`.

user `2` has 3 posts, the first post has id `1`, the second post has id `2`, the third post has id `3`.

The rows of the `posts` table will look like this.

`SELECT * FROM posts;
user_id  id  text
1        1  'Post one from user 1'
2        1  'Post one from user 2'
2        2  'Post two from user 2'
2        3  'Post three from user 2'
1        2  'Post two from user 1'`

I know this can be done by implementing it on the application level on two trips to the database, such as querying the last post id of a particular user and creating the post based on that. But this can introduce collision in a multi-user environment.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding your question properly, but you can increment the id for the post when doing the insert pretty easily by using a subquery in your insert.

```
INSERT INTO posts (user_id, id, text) VALUES
(userIdVar, (SELECT max(id) + 1 FROM posts WHERE user_id = userIdVar), postText);
```

Comment: Thank you!. I think this should work! I'm not aware that this is possible. Do I need to wrap this in a transaction? Or these are atomic already?

Comment: Unsolved for now, since I think this query is not atomic. If two processes access the post row at the same time this will create race condition.

Comment: How is it possible that a user can post two messages at the exact same time?  If you're concerned about races, you can use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` although that can make your transactions more expensive.

Comment: @ChristianSakai also `SELECT max(id) + 1 FROM posts WHERE user_id = userIdVar` won't see uncommited transactions so it's possible that you get the same id numbers.. iam not sure `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` will fix this or not.

Comment: @BShaps There will be several admins that tried to do the same thing like the user (i.e., create, edit, delete, etc). Sorry it wasn't clear in my original problem statement.

Comment: @BShaps @Raymond Nijland I searched for other SO thread, and some answer do say `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750301/how-to-guarantee-atomic-sql-inserts-with-subqueries